# Accessing mysql via terminal

Tags: mysql, terminal

A while back I installed xampp and could not get it to run because the ports were already being used. Someone recommended that I type .. I believe it was: kill all, into the terminal to, I guess, kill the conflicting connections. This worked and I was able to access phpMyAdmin, but then I started having the problem again so i switched to MAMP. Now I can not access MySQL through the terminal. This is what I type in and this is what I get:

```
Macintosh:~ scottmcpherson$ mysql -u root --password=This_is_where_I_typed_my_pw
-bash: mysql: command not found
Macintosh:~ scottmcpherson$
```

I can, however access my database through phpMyAdmin. But the tutorials I'm following only show you how to create a database through the terminal plus I would really like to learn how to do it both ways. So, I'm thinking that the killall command screwed something up, or the other command that someone recommended a while back- which I can't remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adjust your `PATH` environment variable.  Details are here: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/getting-command-line-access-php-and-mysql-running-mamp-osx

In short, open (or create) a `.profile` file in your home directory, and add this line:

export `PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5/bin/:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`

Paths may need to be adjusted depending on the location of your MAMP install.

Comment: Please consider adding some content to your answer. If the link you posted were to go down, your answer would be left without meaning.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I'm having a heck of a time locating .profile. Off hand, do you know where it's located? I searched for it in my finder and couldn't find it.

Comment: .profile is a hidden file - you can access it via the terminal.  If it's not present, you can create one with any text editor.